# Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

Tags: grub, root-filesystem, kernel-panic, lfs

I have created a image file with this commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=linux.img bs=16M count=1024
cfdisk linux.img
mkfs.ext4 linux.img
```

and installed a linux system following the instructions from the book Linux From Scratch 11.3. I have access to this system via chroot, but when I try run it with this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda linux.img -vga std -m 4G
```

the initialization of the system is interrupted by the error described in the title of this question. my file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` looks like this:

```
# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod ext4
#set root=(hd0,2)

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 6.1.11-lfs-11.3" {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.11-lfs-11.3 root=/dev/hda1 ro
```

what I have tried:

1. uncommenting the line `set root=(hd0,2)' and trying the values` hd0,0`or`hd0,1`(the system not even initialize with this, and I got the error`hd0,X not found` after the grub start screen.
2. changing the root value in the line started with linux in the menuentry option to /dev/loopXX (I got the same error).
3. changing the root value in the line started with linux in the menuentry option to /dev/sda1 (in this case, same message, but with the block as `(8,1)`).

Anyone can tell me what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message `hd0,X not found` comes from GRUB, and indicates GRUB configuration file has an error, pointing to a partition that either does not exist or is not readable by GRUB.

The titular error message `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)` means you got through GRUB and into the Linux kernel, but the kernel cannot find the device specified for the root filesystem, i.e. either you are missing a driver that should have been included into your kernel (or initramfs, if you used that... but LFS doesn't), or your `root=/dev/...` kernel boot option is not correct.

More specifically, `unknown-block(0,0)` means the kernel has no clue what block device your root filesystem is supposed to be on; `unknown-block(8,1)` indicates you specified `/dev/sda1` and the kernel understood that but has not been able to find such a partition. The numbers refer to the major & minor numbers of the device node:

```
ls -l /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 May  4 07:56 /dev/sda1
                      ^^^^^
```

---

The first mistake would be here:

```
cfdisk linux.img
mkfs.ext4 linux.img
```

This suggests you first created a partition table (with an unspecified number of partitions of unknown types) and then **overwrote the partition table** by initializing the entire image as a single `ext4` filesystem.

As a result, there will be no partitions at all: in GRUB terminology, there will be no `(hd0,0)` nor `(hd0,1)` nor `(hd0,2)`, only just `(hd0)`.
There also won't be any unallocated space between the MBR partition table and the beginning of the first partition to embed the core image of GRUB into, so you may have seen some warnings when installing GRUB. It is possible that the installer could have adapted to the situation by falling back to an old installation style that is now *seriously* discouraged.

For creating a whole-disk image, I would recommended the following procedure instead:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=linux.img bs=16M count=1024
cfdisk linux.img
losetup -P /dev/loop0 linux.img
ls /dev/loop0*   #you should see loop0 and the first partition as loop0p1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0pX  # replace X with partition number
mkswap /dev/loop0pY     # if you created a swap partition, use this for it and replace Y
...                    # LFS 11.3 chapter 2.6 and the 1st command of chapter 2.7
mount -v -t ext4 /dev/loop0pX $LFS     # the 2nd command of LFS 11.3 chapter 2.7
...                    # continue according to the book
```

Now, in the `grub.cfg` file, the `set root=` entry should be of the form `(hd0,<X-1>)` because Linux starts counting partitions from 1, but GRUB counts them starting from 0. So if you used `/dev/loop0p1` for your `ext4` partition, use `set root=(hd0,0)` for GRUB.

Also, on the `linux` line, the `root=/dev/hda1` refers to the old deprecated non-`libata` drivers for the archaic PATA disk controllers. Most modern Linux disk controller drivers now use the `/dev/sdXN` style names. So even though you may have used `/dev/loop0p1` to create the ext4 filesystem of your LFS image, once that image is presented as a virtual hard disk within the QEMU VM, the kernel will name it `/dev/sda1` unless you made some strange choices in kernel configuration and used different QEMU options. So the last line of your `grub.cfg` should be:

```
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.11-lfs-11.3 root=/dev/sda1 ro
```

(For your current, mis-prepared `linux.img`, you could try `root=/dev/sda` instead, just for fun; it might or might not work.)

Comment: This is a truly brilliant answer.

Comment: your final remark about using `root=/dev/sda` worked, by the way, despite some errors being prompted during the initialization (I managed to login in the system and use it normally so far); i probably will do this the right way later though.

Comment: I thought it might; although the "wrong way" works, it makes the bootloader easier to break by accident than when set up in the correct way. Specifically, if the physical on-disk location of `/boot/grub/i386-pc/*.img` file/s is changed (e.g. by deleting those files & restoring them from backup), the GRUB will most likely fail to boot and you will need to boot from some other media and chroot into the installation to re-run `grub-install` to fix it. BTW, using a disk without partitions like that is sometimes known as the "superfloppy" configuration.